# Calculator form with submit button for each operation

Tags: php, forms, math

I just started learning the basics of php with html and I tried to make a small calculating system.
you have a text input where you type in a number, and another text input where you type a second number. Then you have 4 buttons. "+" , "-" , "*" , "/".

*(Example) : when you click on "+", it takes me to another page where it does the math*

this is the CALCULE.php which is just html:

```
<form action="traitement.php" method="post">
      A : <input type="text" name="A"><br>
      B : <input type="text" name="B"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="+" name="C1"> <input type="submit" value="-" name="C1"> <input type="submit" value="x" name="C1"> <input type="submit" value="/" name="C1">
</form>
```

the second php page is called "traitement.php" where the result shows up, I tried A + B and it works, I don't know how to make a condition for the other buttons :

```
<?php
  $A=$_POST['A'];
  $B=$_POST['B'];


echo $A + $B;
?>
```

and the php code is what I need to learn but nowhere to find an example... Any small help will be very appreciated.

Comment: `$_POST['C1']` will contain the operation selected. You will need to use conditionals to handle its different potential values.

Comment: Like `switch ($_POST['C1']) { case '+': ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might just want an if/else statement. Something like this:

```
if(isset($_POST['C1'])){
  if($_POST['C1'] === '+'){
     echo $A + $B;
  }elseif($_POST['C1']) === '*'){
    echo $A * $B;
  /* etc. etc. */


}else{
  echo "operator not selected";
}
```

More info: https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php